# How to get another node's cookie in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to get the cookie of another node knowing its `nodename`, both from erlang or OS env?

I did not find any `erlang:get_cookie/2`.

Comment: Using `ps auxww` in the OS env could show the cookie it uses, somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security is the main reason for `erlang` cookies, as explained in [Distributed Erlang Security Section](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id87463). If you could get the cookie from a different node only with its `nodename` it won't be secured. Everybody will be able to get your cookie and connect to your machine and do whatever they like.

Although this kind of security is poor because it is just a simple unique value like a password and that's it, you won't be able to get the cookie from other machine using `erlang`.

I would suggest you to read more about it at [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon#cookies) site.

Answer (score 3):

Authentication determines which nodes are allowed to communicate with each other. In a network of different Erlang nodes, it is built into the system at the lowest possible level. Each node has its own **magic cookie**, which is an Erlang atom.

**When a node tries to connect to another node, the magic cookies are compared. If they do not match, the connected node rejects the connection.**

At start-up, a node has a random atom assigned as its magic cookie and the cookie of other nodes is assumed to be nocookie. T**he first action of the Erlang network authentication server (auth) is then to read a file named $HOME/.erlang.cookie.** If the file does not exist, it is created. The UNIX permissions mode of the file is set to octal 400 (read-only by user) and its contents are a random string. An atom Cookie is created from the contents of the file and the cookie of the local node is set to this using erlang:set_cookie(node(), Cookie). This also makes the local node assume that all other nodes have the same cookie Cookie.

Please read: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id87463